# Use vue-flash-message component with multiple instances

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, flash-message

I need some help.

There are two vue components. In each component is a form.

When one of the forms is submitted a flash message should be shown directly over the form and not at some general position.

The problem is that when e.g. form B is submitted the message is shown in component B and A. So I need to use the flash message component with two instances?

```
// app.js

...
import VueFlashMessage from 'vue-flash-message';
Vue.use(VueFlashMessage);
...


// ComponentA

<template>
 <div>
  <flash-message></flash-message>
  <form>
   ...
  </form>
 </div>
</template>
...
methods: {
 update() {
  this.flash('Form A updated', 'success');
 }
}
...

//ComponentB

<template>
 <div>
  <flash-message></flash-message>
  <form>
   ...
  </form>
 </div>
</template>
...
methods: {
 update() {
  this.flash('Form A updated', 'success');
 }
}
...
```

Comment: It's likely not supposed to work the way you want it. You can fork it

Comment: So this will only work if the vue-flash-message component provide this functionality? There is no other way to do this?

Comment: Of course, you can do this yourself. But you can fork the library and modify it you your needs if you don't want to write this functionality from scratch. I'm unaware of other options